# How to redirect stdin back within C program (under Windows)

Tags: c, windows, console-application

I have a simple C program called a.exe, with main loop like this:

```
void input_console()
{
    printf(">>");
    char in_string[256] = {0};
    fgets(in_string, 256, stdin);
    parse(in_string);
}
```

It works like this when I start it and enter commands from my keyboard:

```
>>say_hello
Hello!
>>say_goodbye
Goodbye!
>>
no command found
>>blablablabla
Command blablablabla not recognized
>>
no command found
```

etc.

Now I would like to read input from file instead of the keyboard so I prepared in.txt like this:

```
say_hello
say_goodbye
blablabla
```

After running a.exe < in.txt (this is Windows) I get:

```
>>Hello!
>>Goodbye!
>>Command blablabla not recognized
>>no command found
>>no command found
>>no command found
... (infinite loop)
```

I guess fgets keeps getting EOF here and my parser reaction to EOF is to print no command found message. 
What I would like to do is to be able to return the input stream back to stdin once the input file I used with "<" redirection is over so I can use keyboard again. Something like:

```
if (in_string[0] == EOF)
    stop_using_a_file_as_stdin_and_go_back_to_normal();
```

Is there any way to do that ?

EDIT:
Answer given by Harry Johnston in the comments works:

```
freopen("CON", "r", stdin);
```

or:

```
freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
```

Comment: How about checking the returnvalue of functions, maybe one of them indicates an error? Also, there are functions that allow you to check if a stream is at EOF. That said, switching "back" is impossible, because there is nothing to switch back to.

Comment: Well yeah, it's not technically switching "back" but the question stands: how to redirect what fgets reads to standard input instead of file.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the standard input", it is only "a program's standard input". In your case, that is a file and there is nothing that can change that. Still, let me ask you a question: Why do you need that? Normally, commandline programs just terminate when they reach the end of their input.

Comment: I am asking mainly out of curiosity to understand how Windows handle those things. It seems that somewhere something in the operating system changes where the program gets input from. It also seems that it should be possible to change it from within the program (maybe with some WinAPI calls).

Comment: You can read from the console (bypassing redirection) by opening `CON` or `CONIN$`.  In your case you could stop reading from standard input once you see EOF and start reading from the console.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using input redirection, you could pass the filename as a command-line argument and open it yourself.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *input = stdin;
    if (argc > 2){
        input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
    // ...
```

Then you can switch back easily.

```
    input = stdin;
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this workaround. It's very useful. Still, I am very curious about answer to actual question.